# Wordpress AJAX request always return 0

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress theme and in my frontend I need to show some information when the user hovers over a post preview. I use AJAX to retrieve the needed information instead of loading extra data for each post, but all my AJAX queries return 0.

This is an excerpt of my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pgsc_ajax_get_supporters', 'pgsc_ajax_get_supporters' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_pgsc_ajax_get_supportes', 'pgsc_ajax_get_supporters' );

function pgsc_ajax_get_supporters()
{
  $politicianId = $_POST['postId'];
  $field = get_field_object('lista', $postId);
  $values = get_field("lista", $postId);
  $lists = array();
  foreach($values as $val) {
    $listName = $field["choices"][$val];
    $logo = get_field("logo", $val)["sizes"]["thumbnail"];
    $lists[$listName] = array("permalink" => get_post_permalink($val), "logo" => $logo);
  }
  wp_reset_query();
  echo json_encode($lists);
  wp_die();
}
```

And this is the AJAX call from my JavaScript:

```
function open_supporter_bar(postId, barId)
{
  var bar = "#bar_" + barId;
  jQuery(bar).hide("slow");
  jQuery(bar).html("");
  jQuery.ajax({
    url : pgsc.ajaxurl,
    type : "POST",
    data : {
      action : "pgsc_ajax_get_supporters",
      postId : postId
    },
    success : function(result) {
      alert(result);
      html = compose_supporter_list(result);
      jQuery(bar).html(html);
      jQuery(bar).show("slow");
    },
    error : function(error) {
      alert("Check the error log!");
    }
  });
}
```

I've already tried replacing `wp_die()` with `die()` but the result is the same

Comment: Are you debugging the request? Can you open your developer tools (firefox, chrome, IE, etc) and see the network tab what happens? There are a server error? Can you make a `var_dump($lists)` in your php and see if it appears in the debugger?

Comment: I tried to log `$lists` from my PHP function and nothing appears in my log file. From the browser behaviour it seems all fine (the error function in the JS never gets called), but it's like my PHP function never gets called at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have misspelled your function on the action hook.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_pgsc_ajax_get_supportes', 'pgsc_ajax_get_supporters' );
```

should be:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_pgsc_ajax_get_supporters', 'pgsc_ajax_get_supporters' );
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`wp_send_json`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json) to output json for a wordpress ajax request

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_pgsc_supporters', 'pgsc_ajax_get_supporters' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_pgsc_supporters', 'pgsc_ajax_get_supporters' );

function pgsc_ajax_get_supporters(){
    $politicianId = $_POST['postId'];
    $field = get_field_object('lista', $postId);
    $values = get_field("lista", $postId);
    $lists = array();
    foreach($values as $val){
      $listName = $field["choices"][$val];
      $logo = get_field("logo", $val)["sizes"]["thumbnail"];
      $lists[$listName] = array("permalink" => get_post_permalink($val), "logo" => $logo);
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_send_json($lists);
}
```